# PHP script to rearrange csv data and output as csv

Tags: php, csv

I have the following data in a csv file. 
[image]

I need to rearrange the data and concate it into 2 columns. the columns will be SKU and Feature. Where SKU = SKU and Feature will be derivative from other columns in the following format.

For yellow marked row: Feature column data will be: `Edge:Square Edge;Wide Plank|Finish:Glossy;Smooth|Grade:A(Select & Better/Prestige)|Installation Location:Second Floor;Main Floor........`

I could parse the csv and stucked.

```
$lines = explode( "\n", file_get_contents( '3b.csv' ) );
$headers = str_getcsv( array_shift( $lines ) );
$data = array();
foreach ( $lines as $line ) {

    $row = array();

    foreach ( str_getcsv( $line ) as $key => $field )
       if($headers[$key]=='sku'){
        $row[ $headers[ $key ] ] = str_replace(",",";",$field);
        }
        if($headers[$key]!='sku' && $field!='') {
            $row['feature'] =  $headers[ $key ].":".str_replace(",",";",$field)."|";


        }

    $row = array_filter( $row );

    $data[] = $row;

}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

Anyone please help me to do this or suggest any script to do this.

Comment: So what have you attempted so far and where exactly did you run into problems?

Comment: Consider using PHP's built-in csv commands. In this way no one will have to research this `parsecsv.lib.php` library for you.

Comment: I edited my code. can u please check now?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the actual text of your incoming csv files, so I will assume that parsing it normally will work properly.

I have borrow my script from your next two questions to unconditionally process your data.

The header row's data is used as a lookup array for the feature names.

Code: (untested)

```
$file = fopen("3b.csv", "r");
$headers = fgetcsv($file);
$final_array = [];
while (($row = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
    $sku = $row[0];
    unset($row[0]);
    foreach ($row as $featureNameIndex => $featureValues) {
        foreach (explode(',', $featureValues) as $featureValue) {
            $final_array[] = [
                'sku' => $sku,
                'feature' => "{$headers[$featureNameIndex]}:{$featureValue}"
            ];
        }
    }
}
fclose($file);

var_export($final_array);
```

This approach will generate an indexed array of associative arrays -- each containing two-elements.

Features with multiple values are divided and stored as separate subarrays.